# No web dyno for newly created heroku app

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku, struts2

I have been working on a Java maven web app using Struts2, Hibernate, and tomcat locally for sometime now. I have decided to host the app on Heroku so I signed up and create a new app. I then pushed my app to heroku using git but whenever I visit url I get:

```
 Application Error
 An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again        in a few moments.

 If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When I go to resource page of my app I realize that there is no dyno instance available, so I'm thinking that's my problem. Am I correct and if so how can I create a new one and solve this problem.

Update

I check the logs and I'm getting a H14 - No web processes running.Which suggest that my app has no dyno's indeed. So I tried to add one using the following command:

```
 heroku ps:scale web=1 --app appname
```

But I get "Scaling web process...failed no such type has web". How can I solve this?

Comment: The first thing you should do is check the details logs (by using heroku logs command). It's will give you useful information to debug.

Comment: Have you created your `Procfile`? It should have a web process specified like: `web: bundle exec puma` (example from the Rails world).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your app likely does not have an app server (i.e. its just the raw WAR file without Tomcat). To fix this you have a couple options:

- [WAR Deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment): this is an alternative deployment flow specifically for WAR files. You upload your WAR file to Heroku and Tomcat is bundled for you along with the necessary Procfile. You can do this with either the [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment) or [Eclipse](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse). This is the easiest, but does have some limitations for advanced customizations.
- [Manually add Webapp Runner to your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner). This is a little more work because you have to make changes to your POM and create your own Procfile, but it will allow for further customization and will let you run Webapp Runner locally for better [dev/prod parity](http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).
- [Manually add Jetty Runner to your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner). Same idea as above, but with Jetty, which I've personally found works better with Struts2 apps. [Here is an example](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/axiom) of a Struts2 app I have that uses this approach. Take a look it [POM](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/axiom/blob/master/pom.xml) and [Procfile](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/axiom/blob/master/Procfile) to see how it was done.

Comment: What are the limitation for WAR deployment?

Comment: Mainly that Procfile is not under your direct control, so if you need worker processes or a custom web process, the other options are better. Nonetheless, the [advanced options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#advanced-options) let you still do a good amount of customization to the provided web process. Also, the WAR file uploads can sometimes take longer than the incremental git pushes.

Comment: When you say that struts2 works better with jetty runner, in terms of what?

Comment: I just remember having some context root issues with Tomcat with the example app I listed, but it just worked with Jetty. It was probably a simple config issue, but I just remember Jetty working out of the box.